# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RectangleReadOnly: this Rectangle is read only while creating Rectangle object

Tags: java, itext, unsupportedoperation

I am getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RectangleReadOnly: this Rectangle is read only. 
Getting exception when I am trying to create a Rectangle object and then rotating it.
Jar file used is- com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar

```
Rectangle pg = PageSize.getRectangle("LETTER");
    if (isLandscape) pg = pg.rotate(); (exception coming on this line)
    if (!TextOp.isEmpty(pageBGColor)) {
      pg.setBackgroundColor(PDFUtil.getColor(pageBGColor));
    }
    document_ =  new Document(pg);
```

Comment: Please try again with a more recent version of iText, either 5.5.11 or 7.0.2. Version 2.1.7 is EOL since 2012: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/itext/3557/getting-started-with-itext#t=201703151411361159498&a=versions

Comment: both the version 2.1.7 and 5.5.11 have same code in respective classes.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
Rectangle pg = PageSize.getRectangle("LETTER");
```

according to [a search on GitHub for `RectangleReadOnly`](https://github.com/pdf4j/pdf4j/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RectangleReadOnly&type=) it returns a reference to a predefined `static final Rectangle` that is *implemented* by an object of class `RectangleReadOnly`. This is a specialization of `Rectangle` that enforces its own immutability, so that you cannot modify the "constant" named rectangles you can ask for.

Try instead

```
Rectangle pg = new Rectangle(PageSize.getRectangle("LETTER"));
```

to create a mutable clone of the immutable `Rectangle` object instead.

It could be argued that this is a bug in the library. It should be doing the object clone for you.

Comment: A static final only prevents changing what the reference is from within the class, it doesn't prevent what he's doing form what I can tell. I'm guessing that within the library the object is declared as unmodifiable. I actually ran an equivalent of his code with that jar and didn't get an exception thrown. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Dear Jim Garrison, I tried the solution suggested by you but no luck. Still same exception. 
Rectangle pg = PageSize.getRectangle("LETTER"); 
and 
Rectangle pg = new Rectangle(PageSize.getRectangle("LETTER"));
are doing same thing. Dont know why its not letting change the object.

Comment: Your grepcode link shows the source of `PageSize` in itext 5.1.2. The op indicates that he uses itext 2.1.7. Have you checked whether the class had changed between these versions?

Comment: The grepcode website you linked is not up to date, it does not contain iText 5.5.7 to 5.5.11. iText 7 is also missing on Grepcode. I sent an email to info@grepcode.com to notify them.

Comment: Instead of linking to GrepCode, you could also just link to the actual source on GitHub. I hope you don't mind that I will update your answer?

Comment: Viewing the source on GitHub allows you to use `git blame` so you can see if and when the code changed.

Comment: @user1054949 Did you do a clean build? The code for the constructor  `Rectangle(Rectangle r)` _definitely_ clones the argument and would be returning an instance of `Rectangle`, not `RectangleReadOnly`.  Please do a completely clean build and try again.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thanks. I have further updated the answer and link to more clearly describe the result.